# API or MVC application based on STATIC DataLayer

Tags: c#, static

Imagine a scenario where 1000's of user are accessing either an MVC website or an WebAPI2 that access the Database via a separated DLL DataLayer.

The Datalayer looks like this

```
namespace MyDataLayer
{
    public class Profile
    {
       public static Contact GetContact(int contactId)
       {   
           using (MyDBContext db = new MyDBContext())
           {
               // var contact = some LINQ or EF call 
           }  

           return contact;
       }
    }
}
```

Because the GetContact is "static", would this be a problem having many concurrent users all passing a difference contactId ??

What if I had a class static Dictionary variable that the GetContact method was accessing, would i need to lock it when adding/removing entries?

What about accessing that static variable??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because the context is created and disposed locally. In other words, there are no shared resources *that we can see*, and thus no thread-safety issues either.

If you have a `static Dictionary`, then you want to use the new `ConcurrentDictionary` instead. It's thread-safe.